# Use getTemplate() within KnockoutJS foreach

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I get the following error when I try to use getTemplate() within KnockoutJS foreach.

> Message: Unable to process binding "with: function(){return
>   getChild('my-child') }" Message: getChild is not defined. getChild is
>   not defined

This is how my KOjs template looks...

```
<!-- ko foreach: myObj -->
<div>some markup...</div>
    <!-- ko with: getChild('my-child') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

I'm able to render the template outside of the foreach.

I've tried using `$parent.getChild` but this does not work.

I've also tried this with the more common `getRegion` method below, but without success:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('my-child-area') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Can you share your js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually using the [$parent context property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-2-using-index-parent-and-other-context-properties) worked fine.  I also had a extra space typo in my child template file name, which I had missed when I first tried using `$parent`

```
<!-- ko foreach: myObj -->
<div>some markup...</div>
    <!-- ko with: $parent.getChild('my-child') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: The reason you need `$parent` is because within the foreach loop, you are within the context of the looping item. Without `$parent`, Knockout will be looking for that child element to contain a `getChild` prop, which it does not. Just thought this little tidbit may be useful!

Answer (score 3):

The `getChild` method exists only on UiComponents extending from `uiComponent` (a.k.a. `uiCollection` or `Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection`.
Maybe your component only extends from the `uiElement` (a.k.a. `Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element`), which doesn't have `getChild()`?

Comment: Thanks! I also had a stupid typo. Answered my own question below.

Answer (score 3):

See the code in files and try like this.

grid.phtml

```
<div id="block-sample-grid" data-bind="scope:'sample-grid'" class="block">


    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">

    {

        "#block-sample-grid": {

            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>

        }

    }

</script>

</div>
```

grid.html

```
 <h2>Your seat reservations (<span data-bind="text: seats().length"></span>)</h2>

    <table>
        <thead><tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(data,event){$parent.removeSeat($parent,data);}">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button data-bind="click:addSeat, enable: seats().length < 5 ">Reserve another seat</button>

    <h3 data-bind="visible: totalSurcharge() > 0">
        Total surcharge: $<span data-bind="text: totalSurcharge().toFixed(2)"></span>
    </h3>
```

grid.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
    ],
    function ($, ko, component) {
        "use strict";
        function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = name;
            self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

            self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
                var price = self.meal().price;
                return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
            });
        } 
        return component.extend({
            seats: ko.observableArray([]),
            availableMeals : ko.observableArray([]),
            addSeat : function() {
                var seat = new SeatReservation ("Your Name",this.availableMeals()[0]);
                this.seats.push(seat);
            },
            removeSeat : function(parent,seat) {
                parent.seats.remove(seat);

            },

            addMeal:function(meals){

                for (var i in meals){
                    this.availableMeals.push(meals[i]);
                }

            },


            totalSurcharge : function() {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.seats().length; i++)
                    total += this.seats()[i].meal().price;
                return total;
            },

            initialize: function () {

                this._super();
                this._render();
                this.totalfeeds();

            },
            _render:function(){

                var self = this;
                var meals = [
                    { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
                    { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
                    { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
                ];
                this.addMeal(meals);
                var init_seats = [
                    new SeatReservation ("Henry",this.availableMeals()[0]),
                    new SeatReservation ("Bert",this.availableMeals()[0]),

                ];
                for(var i in init_seats){
                    this.seats.push(init_seats[i]);
                }
            },
            defaults: {
                template: 'Thienphucvx_Knockout/grid',
            },
        });
    }
);
```